# R: how can I find the distance of one point difference from the distribution curve?

Tags: r, distance, normal-distribution

I am trying to find the distance of one point (x) from a distribution I will set for my data X

```
duration <- rpois(500, 10) # For duration data I assume Poisson distributed
hist(duration,
   probability = TRUE, # Instead of frequency
   breaks = "FD",      # For more breaks than the default
   col = "darkslategray4", border = "seashell3")
lines(density(duration - 0.5),   # Add the kernel density estimate (-.5 fix for the bins)
   col = "firebrick2", lwd = 3)
```

if this is the program and one x=32 comes,how can i see how much far it is from the mean of the distribution in R?

Comment: In statistics, this is called a residual.

Comment: In Poisson distribution, mean = variance = lambda where you've set to be 10.

Comment: Are you looking for something more than `32-mean(duration)`?